# VBA for Word - UNC Paths

Tags: vba, ms-word, unc

I have a Word document that uses VBA forms to generate the document content based on selection boxes. The VBA copies and pastes from other word documents into the main document. I use explicit paths to specify where it should go find the word documents.

It would be nice to use UNC paths instead, to remove some of the "explicitness" of the file locations (c:\Files\Example\Content\PROFILE.docx) and maybe replace it with something like "..\Content\Profile.docx "
Example of the code:

```
Sub GenerateProfile()

  Dim currentPathProfile As String

  currentPathProfileText = ActiveDocument.Path

  currentPathProfileText = currentPathProfileText & "c:\Files\Example\Content\PROFILE.docx"

  Documents.Open FileName:=currentPathProfileText
  
  Dim currentPathProfileDoc As Document

  Set currentPathProfileDoc = Documents(1)

  currentPathProfileDoc.Activate
  
  Call CopyWholeContent

  currentPathProfileDoc.Close

  Call PasteWholeContent

End Sub
```

Comment: You're asking about UNC paths but it seems more like you're asking about *relative paths* ?

Answer (score 0):

If the other word documents are in a relative path position to the template holding the code you can do it. It is easier if they are in a subfolder. Generate the path of ThisDocument (your code holder) and use that as a base.
ThisDocument.Path

However, rather than pull from documents, why not have the text stored in your template in the form of AutoText and use that instead? If the information is needed in more than one template, it can be stored in a global template as AutoText. This is much more flexible and less prone to problems, IMO.